# Best way to remove dry seal on paper?

Tags: paper

For example

[image]

I've already tried putting a towel in between the paper with dry seal and flat iron, it makes the job done but Im still looking for easier way

Comment: The way you're using is the best way to minimize the embossing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to get rid of the dry seal, you have to do it that way.

You have to shorten the structure in the paper again.
The seal lenghtend the paper structure.

Using abrasive you can get rid of the seal on one side, but you are then under the smooth paper surface. You are in the structure inside.
So mostly you see it.

On the other side the seal is still there.

Answer (score 1):

If a **copy** of the document will do, then either

- Mask the embossment with plain paper and photocopy.

or

- Place the document on the copier's platen off-centre so that the embossment isn't on the glass and won't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

HACK: Reverse the process.

The dry seal design "in relief" that you see is the result of **embossing** (pushing up) the paper. (Flip the paper over and you will see the opposite—ridges 'become' valleys.)

[image: embossing diagram]

The dry seal is formed by squeezing the page between a deeply engraved surface and another layer made from a mold of the engraving. The result is what you see.

What you are about to do is "burnish" (rub and press) the paper flat again. You'll squeeze the page between a flat, smooth surface and a "burnisher" made from a teaspoon.

The action is similar to squeezing dough between a counter top and a rolling pin to thinify it.

1. Place the embossed page on a smooth flat hard surface—bumpy-side up. The smoother and harder it is will give you superior results. A thick plexiglass cutting board would be ideal. Wood is too soft.
2. Cover the embossed design with a sheet of tracing paper. Without it the texture of the paper will become shiny from the spoon "burnisher."
3. Press the embossed surface flat between the smooth base and the round bottom of the teaspoon. Work your way a little bit at a time across the embossed paper.
   It may help to put your thumb into the indentation of the teaspoon to apply strong pressure in a more controlled manner than by holding the handle. Rocking the spoon slightly, a-bit-at-a-time, over the surface is easier than trying to slide it.
4. Check your work.
5. As an absolutely last resort for a stubborn 'bump', try the *tiniest bit of moisture* on a cotton ball squeezed nearly dry before dabbing on the seal (but for no longer than a microsecond.) Moisture will allow the paper to slightly expand—you don't want that if you can avoid it. If that happens, you must put the page between blotters and carefully 'iron' it dry.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [sandpaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandpaper).

Buy sandpaper with grit around 400, and try gently to remove the seal. If you notice it tears the paper, stop of course.

I didn't try it myself, but sounds like it might work.

Comment: The paper is a uniform thickness. The bumps aren't thicker paper. Using abrasives will give you 'lace.' There's nothing to remove.